# How to import a bulk .js file having relationship with the other .js file in neo4j database?

Tags: neo4j

I am new in neo4j (and cypher) technology and i am trying to import a test file. 
I wanted to import a bulk file of extension "**.js**".....I looked into most of the importing tutorials and official site of neo4j for import of javascript file type (https://neo4j.com/developer/javascript/).

But still I am confused and not able to move forward. Could someone please help me ? Any help or suggestions would be really really appreciable !

**Problem Statement:**

I need to import 2 test files "**state.js**" and "**county.js**" in neo4j. The "county.js" file displays those specific counties present in a particular state (**identified by state_id** ) whereas the "state.js" file displays unique states' label along with a particular state_id

The test file ("state.js") has the following code:

```
const state = [
{ id: "1", label: "State A" }, 
{ id: "2", label: "State B" }, 
{ id: "3", label: "State C" }, 
{ id: "4", label: "State D" }
 ];
  module.exports = state;
```

And the test file ("county.js" ) has data in the format as below:

```
const data = 
     {
      "params": {"state_id":"1"},
      "items":

      [
        {"id":"5001","label":"Test A County"},
     {"id":"5002","label":"Test B County"},
    {"id":"5003","label":"Test C County"},
    {"id":"5004","label":"Test D County"},
    {"id":"5005","label":"Test E County"},
     {"id":"5006","label":"Test F County"}
   ] }
   module.exports = data;
```

so, could someone please let me know how should I import both of these .js files without destroying their relationship ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.js` files are not "bulk" data files -- they are Javascript source code files that appear to be intended for running on [node.js](https://nodejs.org). You can write a node.js application that uses these source files. The [official Javascript neo4j driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/neo4j-driver) would be a good choice for this.

Alternatively, you could create equivalent JSON data files from the arrays in those source files, and use the APOC procedure [apoc.load.json](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_loading_data_from_web_apis_json_xml_csv) to import the data in a Cypher query that uses `CREATE` or `MERGE` to update the DB.

Comment: Thanks @cybersam for such a quick response...I was stuck for 2 days due to it and surfed all most all the contents to fix. I am really really grateful to you. I will try using the neo4j driver but first need to go through the cypher and driver more in depth as it seems i need to push myself more :)